# only allow defined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Is it possible in either gcc/g++ or ms c++ to set a flag which only allows defined behavior? so something like the below gives me a warning or preferably an error

```
func(a++, a, ++a)
```

Comment: I compile using `g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic` or sometimes `g++ -Wall -Weffc++ -ansi -pedantic`.

Comment: I find `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` essential as well.

Comment: @Mark: This won't catch any undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'ma upvote the question because of the splendid answers. OT: legend has it that there was once a compiler that reported 'The compiler was unable to detect any of your errors' instead of '0 errors, 0 warnings'

Comment: @Mark B There are some cases where that's perfectly reasonable; protected destructors are the obvious case.

Comment: I find `-Werror` essential. It treats all warnings as errors. Thus forcing you to fix all warnings before the code compiles. (Note in addition to all the flags from @Rob above).

Answer (score 8):

Undefined and unspecified behavior is designated so in the standard specifically because it could cause undue burden on the implementation to diagnose all examples of it (or it would be impossible to determine).

It's expected that the programmer take care to avoid those areas that are undefined.

For your stated example it should be fairly obvious to a programmer to *just not write that code in the first place*.

That being said, `g++ -Wall` will catch some bad code, such as missing return in a non-void function to give one example.

EDIT: @sehe also points out `-Wsequence-point` which will catch this precise code construct, although there should be a sequence point between evaluation of each argument (the order in which arguments is evaluated is unspecified however).

Answer (score 7):

GNU C++ has the following

```
   -Wsequence-point
       Warn about code that may have undefined semantics because of violations of sequence point rules in the C and C++ standards.
```

This will correctly flag the invocation you showed

```
  -Wstrict-overflow

  -Wstrict-overflow

   -fstrict-aliasing
   -fstrict-overflow
```

HTH

Comment: +1. You can also use `-Werror=sequence-point`, so g++ will refuse to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, consider the following:

```
int badfunc(int &a, int &b) {
    return func(a++, b++);
}
```

This has undefined behavior if `a` and `b` have the same referand. In general the compiler cannot know what arguments will be passed to a function, so it can't reliably catch this case of undefined behavior. Therefore it can't catch all undefined behavior.

Compiler warnings serve to identify *some* instances of undefined behavior, but never all.

In theory you could write a C++ implementation that does vast numbers of checks at runtime to ensure that undefined behavior is always identified and dealt with in ways defined by that implementation. It still wouldn't tell you at compile time (see: halting problem), and in practice you'd probably be better off with C#, which was designed to make the necessary runtime checks reasonably efficient...

Even if you built that magical checking C++ implementation, it still might not tell you what you really want to know, which is whether your code is correct. Sometimes (hang on to your seats), it is implementation-defined whether or not behavior is undefined. For a simple example, `tolower((char)-1);` has defined behavior[*] if the `char` type is unsigned, but undefined behavior if the `char` type is signed.

So, unless your magical checking implementation makes all the same implementation choices as the "real" implementation that you want your code to run on, it won't tell you whether the code has defined behavior for the set of implementation choices made in the "real" implementation, only whether it has defined behavior for the implementation choices made in the magical checking implementation.

To know that your code is correct and portable, you need to know (for starters) that it produces no undefined behavior for *any* set of implementation choices. And, for that matter, for *any* input, not just the inputs used in your tests. You might think that this is a big deficiency in C++ compared to languages with no undefined behavior. Certainly it is inconvenient at times, and affects how you go about sandboxing programs for security. In practice, though, for you to consider your code correct you don't just need it to have defined behavior, you need the behavior to match the specification document. That's a *much* bigger problem, and in practice it isn't very much harder to write a bug in (say) Java or Python than it is in C++. I've written countless bugs in all three, and knowing that in Java or Python the behavior was defined but wrong didn't help me all that much.

[*] Well, the *result* is still implementation-defined, it depends on the execution character set, but the implementation has to return the correct result. If `char` is signed it's allowed to crash.

Answer (score 2):

This gave me a good laugh. Sorry about that, didn't mean any offense; it's a good question.

There is no compiler on the planet that only allows 100% defined behavior. It's the undefined nature of things that makes it so hard. There are a lot of cases taken up in the standard, but they're often too vague to efficiently implement in a compiler.

I know Clang developers showed some interest to adding that functionality, but they haven't started as far as I know.

The only thing you can do now and in the near/far future is cranking up the warning level and strictness of your compiler. Sadly, even in recent versions, MSVC is a pain in that regard. On warning level 4 and up, it spits some stupid warnings that have nothing to do with code correctness, and you often have to jump through hoops to get them to go away.

GCC is better at that in my personal experience. I personnally use these options, ensuring the strictest checks (I currently know of)

```
-std=c++0x -pedantic -Wextra -Weffc++ -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing
```

I of course ensure zero warnings, if you want to enforce even that, just add `-Werror` to the line above and any error will error out. It's mostly the `std` and `pedantic` options that enforce Standard behavior, `Wextra` catches some off-chance semi-errors.

And of course, compile your code with different compilers if possible (and make sure they are correctly diagnosing the problem by asking here, where people know what the Standard says/means).

Comment: You're missing `-Wconversion`!

Comment: Wow, you're right. It got one case of a `size_t` -> `int` conversion. Gotta love C++ for pedantry `:)`

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Mark's answer, I just thought I should let you know...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    printf("%d\n", func(a++, a, ++a)); /* line 11 */
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code above with `gcc -Wall`, I get the following warnings:

```
test.c:11: warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined
test.c:11: warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined
```

because of `a++` and `++a`, I suppose. So to some degree, it's been implemented. But obviously we can't expect all undefined behavior to be recognized by the compiler.